# How to know if text to speech is finished talking?

Tags: android-studio, text-to-speech, android-developer-api, google-text-to-speech, android-speech-api

I am trying to make a text to speech app and all my code is fine. 
I want to execute some code when it has completed speaking. 
I have no idea what to write and where to write that code.
I tried finding many solutions but they did not work for me.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextToSpeech tts;
private EditText et;
private SeekBar sb_pitch;
private SeekBar sb_speed;
private Button bt;
private Button bt2;
private Button bt3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        bt = findViewById(R.id.bt);
        bt2 = findViewById(R.id.bt2);
        bt3 = findViewById(R.id.bt3);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {

                if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
                {
                  tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                 bt.setEnabled(true);
                }

            }
        });

        et = findViewById(R.id.et);
        sb_pitch = findViewById(R.id.sb_pitch);
        sb_speed = findViewById(R.id.sb_speed);


        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(et.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Text Detected!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    bt.setEnabled(false);
                    sb_pitch.setEnabled(false);
                    sb_speed.setEnabled(false);
                    speak();
                }
            }
        });


        bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tts.stop();
                bt.setEnabled(true);
                sb_pitch.setEnabled(true);
                sb_speed.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        bt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (tts.isSpeaking())
                {
                    et.setText("");
                    bt.setEnabled(false);
                    sb_pitch.setEnabled(false);
                    sb_speed.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else {
                    et.setText("");
                    bt.setEnabled(true);
                    sb_pitch.setEnabled(true);
                    sb_speed.setEnabled(true);
                    sb_pitch.setProgress(50);
                    sb_speed.setProgress(50);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void speak()
    {

        String text = et.getText().toString();

        float pitch = (float)sb_pitch.getProgress() / 50;
        if(pitch<0.1)pitch = 0.1f;

        float speed = (float)sb_speed.getProgress() / 50;
        if(speed<0.1)speed = 0.1f;

        tts.setPitch(pitch);
        tts.setSpeechRate(speed);

        tts.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        if(tts!=null)
        {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Use the `UtteranceProgressListener()`

Comment: Where exactly do i use it in the code?

Answer (score 1):

This is how i did it on my app

```
textToSpeech=new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                int result=textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

                if (result==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA||result==TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
                    Log.i("TextToSpeech","Language Not Supported");
                }

                textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                        Log.i("TextToSpeech","On Start");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                        Log.i("TextToSpeech","On Done");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(String utteranceId) {

                    }
                });

            }else {
                Log.i("TextToSpeech","Initialization Failed");
            }
        }
    });
```

then on your button click

```
textToSpeech.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,TextToSpeech.ACTION_TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED);
```